# C++ ERROR resending parameters to template function (matrix argument)

Tags: c++, function, templates, matrix, arguments

Why this doesn't work in C++14?
It's a simplified example of my problem.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename type, size_t size1, size_t size2>
void f1(type (&matrix)[size1][size2]){

}

void f2(size_t &size1, size_t &size2){
    double matrix[size1][size2];
    f1(matrix);
}

int main()
{
    size_t size1=100;
    size_t size2=200;
    f2(size1,size2);
    return 0;
}
```

**main.cpp:13:14: error: no matching function for call to 'f1(double [size1][size2])'**

Thank you!

---

**----EDIT 1----**

However, I'm not sure why this first example works and the second one doesn't works.

**EXAMPLE 1 -> WORKS**

```
template <typename type, size_t size1, size_t size2>
void f1(type (&matrix)[size1][size2]){ }


int main()
{
    double matrix[100][200];
    f1(matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

**EXAMPLE 2 -> NOT WORKS**

```
template <typename type, size_t size1, size_t size2>
void f1(type (&matrix)[size1][size2]){ }

int main()
{
    size_t size1=100;
    size_t size2=200;

    double matrix[size1][size2];
    f1(matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

**----EDIT 2----**

**USING CONST**

**EXAMPLE 1 - USING CONST 1 FUNCTION -> WORKS**

```
template <typename type, size_t size1, size_t size2>
    void f1(type (&matrix)[size1][size2]){ }

    int main()
    {
        const size_t size1=100;
        const size_t size2=200;

        double matrix[size1][size2];
        f1(matrix);
        return 0;
    }
```

**EXAMPLE 2 - USING CONST 2 FUNCTION -> NOT WORKS**

```
template <typename type, size_t size1, size_t size2>
void f1(type (&matrix)[size1][size2]){

}

void f2(const size_t &size1, const size_t &size2){
    double matrix[size1][size2];
    f1(matrix);
}

int main()
{
    const size_t size1=100;
    const size_t size2=200;
    f2(size1,size2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ doesn't support variable length arrays.

Answer (score 0):

There are no variable length arrays in C++. However, most of C++ compilers do support them as an extension. But even when they do support this, the size of those arrays is not known at compile time, and so template deduction can't happen.

As a result compiler is giving you the error, though I admit, not the most easiest to understand one.

Comment: Thank you SergeyA! It was very useful. However, can you explain me my post edition?

Comment: @tronic exact same reason. One is using an array sized at compile time and the other isn't. [Change `size_t size1=100;` and it's buddy to be `const`](https://ideone.com/65aXFN) and you can rock and roll. Array indexes must be `const` to get all of the standard-guaranteed goodies.

Comment: @tronic because in your other example your arrays are of fixed, compile-time know sizes, and template deduction works.

Comment: @user4581301 And what happend with this? [Using const with two functions doesnt works.](https://ideone.com/BKzooS)

Comment: @tronic `void f2(const size_t &size1, const size_t &size2)` `size1` and `size2` are not compile-time constant. `size1` and `size2` are constant within that function, but the function can be called with [any valid `size_t` at runtime.](https://ideone.com/QwQpJu)